# Transcription of Yamāntaka mantra chanting fragment

Tags: vajrayana, translation, mantra, tantra

I am a total outsider not well-versed in the Buddhist tradition, and apologize in advance if some of the terms/names I'll write are placed out of context or misused.

To cut the story short, I am looking for a transcription (and possibly translation into English) of a certain Tantric overtone singing (Rgyud Skad) [fragment](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hg7c1ty973k403o/fragment.wav?dl=0), used as a sound effect at the end of each level in Painkiller 2004 videogame.

According to my research, I believe it to be a sample from Yamāntaka mantra as performed by Gyütö Monks on [this](https://www.discogs.com/en/Tibetan-Institute-Of-Performing-Arts-Dhama-Suna-%E0%BD%96%E0%BD%A2%E0%BD%98%E0%BD%A6%E0%BD%A6/release/1327226) album, [4th track](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1av0jtonl5epo2/mantra.mp3?dl=0), starting at 0:32 time mark.

I tried to make sense of the chanting by reading [Meditation on Vajrabhairava](http://lit.lib.ru/img/i/irhin_w_j/vadjrabhajrava/victory-over-evil.pdf) and attempting to "sync" the text by looking at the places where performers play the bell — obviously, I have little to no idea of what I am doing and that didn't ring any bells (pun intended) :)

Comment: This is a really interesting niche question that I wish I knew how to answer. I upvoted it all the same. I'll see if anyone I know knows anyone who could even begin to identify it. Have you also considered asking ethnomusicologists?

Comment: @Caoimhghin thanks for the suggestion! I'll happily ask around if there exist communication mediums for that (forums, mailing lists, private messages &c). Can you give me any pointers in this regard?